# After subclass in the viewDidLoad the [super viewDidLoad] gets called, but the methods do not get executed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, c, inheritance

I got a question about subclassing.

I start with my first view: 
in my .h file:

```
@interface viewAController : UIViewController
```

in my .m file:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSLog(@"Begin view"); 
udpSocket = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    NSError *error = nil;

if (![udpSocket bindToPort:12345 error:&error]) //check ff of dit werkt!
{
    NSLog(@"F you");
    return;
}

NSLog(@"Derde line"); 
if (![udpSocket beginReceiving:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"Screw you!");
    return;
}   
}
```

Porting and beginreceiving goes well. 
and then when I subclass viewAController:

```
@interface viewBController : viewAController
```

in my .m file:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad]; 
}
```

I am expecting that my subclass [viewBController], will display all of the NSLogs, because Im calling the super  viewDidLoad.

Instead it is saying: F you! 
Oke I understand that I can only bind once to the port, BUT Im expecting an error message, this does not show.

So I delete the binding and then I get Screw you, apparently I cannot say beginreceiving when Im not binding to a port. Without these two methods it works just fine though, it is printing everything out of the parent.

QUESTIONS: 
Should I bind? I actually only need to listen to port 12345, should I just implement this differently?

Should I work without bind and without beginreceiving? I think I prefer with binding so that I wont listen to all of my ports.

Why cant I do beginreceiving when I dont bind?

How can I show the error?? Cause it is not printing any errors ...

greetz

Comment: That's a reasonable thing to expect.  Put a breakpoint in viewBController's viewDidLoad to see if it's being called and, if so, trace it into viewAController.

Comment: How are you calling the viewBController? Try to put a NSLog / breakpoint in the viewDidLoad in viewBController to see if it gets called at all.

Comment: I fixed it and updated my question :). The example I first gave indeed works lol. The one I have written now is the real issue :).

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is right.But i have only one question to ask whether you have added the object of derived ViewController to some View.
Unless you wont add it you wont get the didLoad Of your superclass get fired.
Check by adding the object of your derived View to SomeView.

Comment: I fixed it and updated my question :). The example I first gave indeed works lol. The one I have written now is the real issue :).

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong you are doing

```
NSLog("@Hi there!");
```

you have to use

```
NSLog(@"Hi there!");
```

And if this is a typo (I hope it is) you have to add your sub class to some where using add subview or pushing it.

Comment: I fixed it and updated my question :). The example I first gave indeed works lol. The one I have written now is the real issue :).